# Reversed light switch then quit

Tags: switch, light

I have a 1998 mobile home. There are two light switches that reversed on/off. The first is in laundry area, it has stopped function and the light remains on. The Second is in kitchen and has reversed.

Have looked for other switches and have had no luck. So it can't be 3 way switches doing this.

My question is how to fix. They both have on/off labels

Comment: First turn off the breaker and loosen the switches from the wall, do not remove any wires.  Take a picture.  There is a slight possibility of a simple switch reversing(like 1 in 10,000,000), so if it happen buy lotto.  It is much more of a chance that someone put the switches upside down(on is bottom/down).

Comment: The fix is replacement.  A single simple switch will have just two screws on a side plus a ground screw.  Three way switches have two screws plus another screw on the opposite side plus a ground(green) screw.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a classically midwired two-way circuit, with one of the switches installed "backward".

Comment: Do you have ANY switches in your house that you never use, or that you don't know what they do?  ANY.  Including behind furniture.